# jpype accessing java mehtod/variable whose name is reserved name in python

Tags: java, python, type-conversion, reserved-words, jpype

Any idea how this can be done? ie, if we have a variable defined in java as below

`public Class Foo {
   String pass = "foo";
}`

how can I access this via jpype since pass is a reserved keyword? I tried
`getattr(Jpype.JClass(Foo)(), "pass")` but it fails to find the attribute named pass

Answer (score 1):

Figured out that jpype appends an `"_"` at the end for those methods/fields in its source code. So you can access it by Jpype.JClass("Foo").pass_

Wish it's documented somewhere

Comment: stackoverflow filter the underscore, so jpype appends underscore at the end for names conflict with python keyword

Answer (score 0):

unfortunally Fields or methods conflicting with a python keyword can’t be accessed

Comment: hmm, that's a bummer. Was hoping to see if there is a way to pass the name as string directly to jvm to invoke java method/field.

Comment: according to official documenation [link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/JPype1-py3) 
Known Bugs/Limitations

    Java classes outside of a package (in the <default> package) cannot be imported.
    Fields or methods conflicting with a python keyword can’t be accessed.
    Because of lack of JVM support, you cannot shutdown the JVM and then restart it.
    Some methods rely on the “current” class/caller. Since calls coming directly from python code do not have a current class, these methods do not work. The User Manual lists all the known methods like that.